# Magento installer throws writable directory permission error in WAMP

Tags: php, magento, windows-10, wampserver, magento2

Hi so I am running Windows 10 with WAMP. I am trying to install Magento 2. 
I have everything pathed out correctly and when I go to localhost/magento/ I get to the magento installer screen. However for the readiness check it has issues with file permissions for the following:

```
"C:/wamp/www/magento/app/etc" writable directory permission.
"C:/wamp/www/magento/var" writable directory permission.
"C:/wamp/www/magento/pub/media" writable directory permission.
"C:/wamp/www/magento/pub/static" writable directory permission.
```

My question is how do I get rid of these errors so I can proceed to the next step in the installer?

I've already resolved the PHP settings and extension check errors that I had.

Comment: Can you check if those directories exist and are not `readonly`?

Comment: Hi I resolved it yesterday, stupidly was setting the whole magento folder as not readonly rather than each individual error folder.

Comment: Please add that as an answer and mark as accepted, so that it can help others.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck readonly on all subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

Just move or rename the .htaccess inside pub/static. See if it works.